After upgrade of flutter to latest version getting below error
lib/main.dart:103:50: Error: The getter 'headline4' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

The issue you're facing arises from changes to Flutter's TextTheme class API. In recent Flutter updates, certain text styles within the TextTheme class have been deprecated or renamed to align with Material Design guidelines.
In Flutter 2.5 and above versions, headline4 has been renamed to headlineLarge.
So to fix the error, you need to replace headline4 with headlineLarge in you code.
